# Eloquent hasOne relationship: use concat of two fields as local key

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables that are related in this manner:

CITIES
id
name
country
admin1_code

ADMIN1
name
code --> this is "." from CITIES

Now, I have to join on ADMIN1.code = CONCAT(CITIES.country,'.',CITIES.admin1_code)

I want to use Eloquent hasOne method for relationships. How is it possible to set the local key as a concatenation of two fields? I am using Laravel 5.0

Many thanks,
    Francesco

Comment: Exactly same problem with geonames database. Did you find any solution? At this moment i think to divide this field on export to database.